# python: csv file to json format and try to call a column without the another column in the data

Tags: python, json

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Promotion Code|Promotion Name|Coupon Code|Coupon Name
E00000002|Gift Free Coin||
||000420|new join $300
E000000001|VIP -10%|006969|new join $300
```

And I need the result will like this:

```
[{"New_column": [{"type": "promo_code", "description": "Gift Free Coin", "redeem": "false"}]}, {"New_column": [{"coupon_code": 000420, "type": "coupon_code", "description": "new join $300", "redeem": "false"}]},{"New_column":[{"type":"promo_code","description":"VIP -10%","redeem":"false"},{"type":"coupon","description":"new join $300","redeem":"false","coupon_code":006969}]
```

I was trying to do this but still fail

This is my code:

```
import csv
import json
from os import sep

with open('tran_test.csv') as file:
    dict_input = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
    next(dict_input, None)
    output = []
    for line in dict_input:
        promotion_code = line[0]
        promotion_name = line[1]
        coupon_code = line[2]
        coupon_name = line[3]
        print(line)
        coupon = {}
        if coupon_code == '' and promotion_code !='':
            coupon['type'] = 'promo_code'
            coupon['description'] = promotion_name
            coupon['redeem'] = 'false'
        elif coupon_code != '' and promotion_code == '':
            coupon['coupon_code'] = coupon_code
            coupon['type'] = 'coupon_code'
            coupon['description'] = coupon_name
            coupon['redeem'] = 'false'
        # elif (coupon_code != '' and promotion_code != ''):
        # 
        else:
            None
        output_obj = {}
        output_obj['New_column'] = [coupon]
        output.append(output_obj)

print(json.dumps(output))
```

And the result is:

```
[{"New_column": [{"type": "promo_code", "description": "Gift Free Coin", "redeem": "false"}]}, {"New_column": [{"coupon_code": "000420", "type": "coupon_code", "description": "new join $300", "redeem": "false"}]}, {"New_column": [{}]}]
```

I have some problems

I don't know how to build a "New_column" if promo and coupon is not null. And the coupon_code must be int but if I change the coupon_code type to int, the leading zero will remove. But I need to keep the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can can afford some refactoring

```
if coupon_code and promotion_code:
    # handle case for both not null
elif coupon_code:
    # handle case for coupon code not null and promo null
elif promotion_code:
    # handle case for promo code not null and coupon null
else:
   # both null
```

This is way more readable IMHO

In your approach, you did not check for both not null first, which caused it to get into the first or second if conditions. You should handle that case first and then the rest of the cases.